# Convert FileUpload to X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, file-upload, encryption, certificate, digital-certificate

How can I convert an uploaded file to an X509Certificate2 variable?

I have tried using the following code but it is not working:

```
public bool hasPublicKey(FileUpload file)
{
    bool check = false;

    try
    {
         X509Certificate2 cert = (X509Certificate2)file.PostedFile.InputStream;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
         check = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly are you uploading? Is it a certificate or another type of file?

Comment: I already have another method which checks that the extension of the file corresponds to the extension of a certificate.  Now, I want to convert the uploaded file into the X509Certificate2 data type so that I can get the public key from it.  However, Visual Studio is giving me this error message: Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the uploaded file is a valid certificate you should have a look at the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148413.aspx) or [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148437.aspx) method in the X509Certificate2 class.

You'll see that you need to something like this:

```
var fileLength = file.PostedFile.ContentLength;
var certdata = new byte[fileLength];

file.FileContent.Read(certData, 0, fileLength);

var cert = new X509Certificate2(certData);
```

*(code not verified but it, or something very similar, should work).*

Comment: He already has the `InputStream`. I think `cert.Import(file.PostedFile.InputStream)` should be enough.

Comment: @StefanM: There is no `Import(Stream)` overload.

Comment: @JoeBorg: Ah Yes. `FileBytes` works aswell. Forgot about that property.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public bool hasPublicKey(FileUpload file)
    {
        bool check = false;

        try
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(file.FileBytes);

            if (cert.PublicKey != null)
            {
                check = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            check = false;
        }
        return check;
    }
```